# Responsive Nav Menus ala uchicago.edu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to take the top and left nav menus of my site so that when sized for mobile - they form two "stacked" dropdown menus at the top {see uchicago.edu}

Answer (score 0):

This is default behaviour of [Bootstrap's Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)